# Goland cannot run debug on macos

Tags: debugging, go, goland

I use Goland not enter debug mode. Cannot enter breakpoint mode. Can't see real-time parameter changes.

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/zhaoziqian/Documents/gopath #gosetup
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o 
/private/var/folders/4g/l31t9xvs1hz3slt5s90ggtr80000gn/T/___go_run_str_go -gcflags "all=-N -l" /Users/zhaoziqian/Documents/gopath/src/goweb/data/str1/str.go #gosetup
/Applications/GoLand.app/Contents/plugins/go/lib/dlv/mac/dlv --listen=localhost:61746 --headless=true --api-version=2 --backend=default exec /private/var/folders/4g/l31t9xvs1hz3slt5s90ggtr80000gn/T/___go_run_str_go -- #gosetup

could not launch process: decoding dwarf section info at offset 0x0: too short

Debugger finished with exit code 1
```

Help me,please!

Answer (score 2):

right now, u can update the go sdk to unstable version 1.16 to fix it~

Answer (score 1):

If you include the package "plugin" then this is a known issue, see https://golang.org/issues/23733

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no known solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Good news!  GoLand has provided an update.  I had this problem with 2018.1 and went away with version 2019.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use delve for debug with https://github.com/go-delve/delve. It is recommends by developer:

> Note that Delve is a better alternative to GDB when debugging Go
>   programs built with the standard toolchain.

For instance it native supports command line, or you can use it with you IDE.